# Can InstantiateTemplateRequest return more than one value?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

As I understand the `InstantiateTemplateRequest` returns a collection of entities with "Subject" and "Description" attributes, however most of the examples I've seen treat the collection as if it only contains one value. Is there a case where it can return multiple values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg308024(v%3Dcrm.8)) says:

> **InstantiateTemplateRequest Class**
>
> Contains the parameters that are needed to create **an email** message
>   from a template (email template).

So intended to receive a single entity in response entity collection.

For example, [this blog](https://lazarus987.wordpress.com/2017/11/05/crm-render-email-template-instantiatetemplaterequest/) also explains this behavior by assuming only one entity. Since you are passing `templateId`, `contactId` - this is going to generate a single email based on that template & contact record data.

```
InstantiateTemplateRequest instTemplateReq = new InstantiateTemplateRequest
{
    TemplateId = templateId,
    ObjectId = contactId,
    ObjectType = "contact"
};
InstantiateTemplateResponse instTemplateResp = (InstantiateTemplateResponse)service.Execute(instTemplateReq);

Entity template = instTemplateResp.EntityCollection.Entities[0];
```